# Eloquent float values be rounded when set and get laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When i try get lat,lng from db. it is rounded but i wanna get exactly.

- Value from db: `float(48.835792541503906), float(2.280343294143677)`
- Value when get: `float(48.835792541504), float(2.2803432941437)`

That is also problem when save to db.

How to solve that ?

Comment: What precision do you have set for the database fields your saving?

Comment: lat, lng field has double(20,15) type.

Comment: Show some code please. How are you storing and retrieving the values. Are you casting them somehow? FYI, if you want precision you shouldn't use float

Comment: I use DOUBLE(20,15) for lat, lng fields.
Code as:
 - when save data: Item:create($data);
 - when get data: Item:find($id)

Answer (score 0):

Float is not right data type for your data. Try [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).
I assume you are using MySQL but syntax is similar to other SQL databases.

Comment: I use DOUBLE(20,15) for lat, lng fields. Code as: - when save data: Item:create($data); - when get data: Item:find($id)

Comment: @RyanLe Float and Double are floating point types. This is from mysql manual: Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help @ikurcubic